IR2104 not producing PWM signal
I made this simulation circuit by the reference of its datasheet. I want to simulate the input PWM signal from MCU (ESP32) and control on/off of IR2104 by ESP32 too. But the problem is, this circuit is not working (bad PWM signal from IR2104). As you can see from oscilloscope, Signal 1 is for PWM, signal 2 is HIGH, and signal 3 is LOW. PWM Freq is 39 kHz. What am I missing? I have tried to change C1 value from 10 nF to 22 µF but still nothing. Also C2 is set for 100 nF.



The gate resistors are a bit high, the bootstrap capacitor C1 is rather small but in general nothing that wouldn't really work in simulation. My MOSFET driver model didn't accept a 3.3V input voltage at all (although IR2104S datasheet says otherwise), I needed 5V. The duty cycle is at 80%.



I made another simulation project and it was working. Probably something error with the file idk.

Yeah i want to implement this design into real PCB and I only have 100ohms resistor for gate
